# Stability function at infinity of a runge-kutta method

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

Recently, I have been studying some bits of numerical analysis and
have managed to derive the stability function of a Runge-Kutta method.
What I got is as follows

$R\left(z\right)=1+zb^{\top}\left(I-zA\right)^{-1}\overset{\rightharpoonup}{1}$

Where $I$ is the identity and $\overset{\rightharpoonup}{1}$ is
a vector of ones.

I keep seeing that $R\left(\infty\right)=1-b^{\top}A^{-1}\overset{\rightharpoonup}{1}$
but I have no idea how you get from one to the other.

Any help is greatly appreciated with many thanks in advance!

Comment: You have essentially $\dfrac{z}{1-za}=\dfrac1{z^{-1}-a}$ if $A$ were a scalar $a$. This carries over to the matrix case.

Answer (score 1):

Spelling out the comment by Lutz, you can use the property that for nonzero $z$ you have $$(I - z A)^{-1} = \big( z (I/z - A ) \big)^{-1} = z^{-1} (I/z - A)^{-1}.$$
As a consequence, \begin{align}
R(z) &= 1 + z b^T (I - zA) \vec{1} \\
&= 1 + z b^T z^{-1} (I/z - A)^{-1} \vec{1} \\
&= 1 + b^T (I/z - A)^{-1} \vec{1}
\end{align}
Now let $z \to \infty, i.e., I/z \to 0$ and you obtain
$$\lim_{z \to \infty} R(z) = 1 + b^T (-A)^{-1} \vec{1} = 1 - b^T A^{-1} \vec{1}.$$